# HQL query for accessing parent class on the basis child collection syntax

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have person class which is composing the list of address class. Now I want to write the HQL which will return me *only* Person objects with atleast one address(more the zero).

will it do like "From Person where count(personaddressList) > 0"

Answer (score 2):

```
select p from Person p where size(p.addresses) > 0
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_arithmetic and/or http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions

Comment: Thanks..! The page you gave.. is abt JPQL, I wanted to have HQL.

Comment: HQL is a superset of JPQL. Any JPQL query is a valid HQL query.

Answer (score 0):

HQL:

```
from Person p where size(p.addresses) > 0
```

Or if you are using associations with the domain classes, then:

```
if (p.getAddresses().size() > 0){
    ...
}
```